# twitter bootstrap carousel not pausing on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a video on one slide of my bootstrap carousel and need it to pause whenever the video is playing. However, whenever the mouse hovers over the slide, it does not pause. Any suggestions?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000,
      pause: "hover"
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
       <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
       </ol>
       <div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/gradient.png">
          <!-- <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#3f55c0:#3f55c0/text:First slide" alt="First slide"> -->
          <div class="container">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">

                <h1>Better with a buddy.</h1>
                <h3>Need a truck? Connect with a buddy in the community that can help! </h3> 
              <a href="#download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg try">Try buddyTruk</button></a>
              <a href="/about"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg learn">Learn more</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
        //VIDEO EMBED
        <div id="wistia_dgoosakyuf" class="wistia_embed" style="width:405px;height:228px;"><div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject"><meta itemprop="name" content="buddyTruk" /><meta itemprop="duration" content="PT1M24S" /><meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/9bce8979b8e339f6d582526370a2eb0de307958e.bin" /><meta itemprop="contentURL" content="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/675386773fd5dab2b84da8770c511b8dd16e2e5e.bin" /><meta itemprop="embedURL" content="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/flash/embed_player_v2.0.swf?2013-10-04&autoPlay=false&banner=true&controlsVisibleOnLoad=true&customColor=fc7f1a&endVideoBehavior=default&fullscreenDisabled=true&hdUrl%5B2pass%5D=true&hdUrl%5Bext%5D=flv&hdUrl%5Bheight%5D=720&hdUrl%5Bsize%5D=27841352&hdUrl%5Btype%5D=hdflv&hdUrl%5Burl%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fembed-ssl.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2F5801df83c75112901570dca8a180646a44cc1d07.bin&hdUrl%5Bwidth%5D=1280&mediaDuration=84.0&playButtonVisible=true&showPlayButton=true&showPlaybar=true&showVolume=true&stillUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fembed-0.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2F9bce8979b8e339f6d582526370a2eb0de307958e.jpg%3Fimage_crop_resized%3D405x228&unbufferedSeek=false&videoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fembed-ssl.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2F675386773fd5dab2b84da8770c511b8dd16e2e5e.bin" /><meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2014-02-16T19:35:41Z" /><object id="wistia_dgoosakyuf_seo" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" style="display:block;height:228px;position:relative;width:405px;"><param name="movie" value="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/flash/embed_player_v2.0.swf?2013-10-04"></param><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"></param><param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param><param name="flashvars" value="autoPlay=false&banner=true&controlsVisibleOnLoad=true&customColor=fc7f1a&endVideoBehavior=default&fullscreenDisabled=true&hdUrl%5B2pass%5D=true&hdUrl%5Bext%5D=flv&hdUrl%5Bheight%5D=720&hdUrl%5Bsize%5D=27841352&hdUrl%5Btype%5D=hdflv&hdUrl%5Burl%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fembed-ssl.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2F5801df83c75112901570dca8a180646a44cc1d07.bin&hdUrl%5Bwidth%5D=1280&mediaDuration=84.0&playButtonVisible=true&showPlayButton=true&showPlaybar=true&showVolume=true&stillUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fembed-0.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2F9bce8979b8e339f6d582526370a2eb0de307958e.jpg%3Fimage_crop_resized%3D405x228&unbufferedSeek=false&videoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fembed-ssl.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2F675386773fd5dab2b84da8770c511b8dd16e2e5e.bin"></param><embed src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/flash/embed_player_v2.0.swf?2013-10-04" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" bgcolor=#000000 flashvars="autoPlay=false&banner=true&controlsVisibleOnLoad=true&customColor=fc7f1a&endVideoBehavior=default&fullscreenDisabled=true&hdUrl%5B2pass%5D=true&hdUrl%5Bext%5D=flv&hdUrl%5Bheight%5D=720&hdUrl%5Bsize%5D=27841352&hdUrl%5Btype%5D=hdflv&hdUrl%5Burl%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fembed-ssl.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2F5801df83c75112901570dca8a180646a44cc1d07.bin&hdUrl%5Bwidth%5D=1280&mediaDuration=84.0&playButtonVisible=true&showPlayButton=true&showPlaybar=true&showVolume=true&stillUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fembed-0.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2F9bce8979b8e339f6d582526370a2eb0de307958e.jpg%3Fimage_crop_resized%3D405x228&unbufferedSeek=false&videoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fembed-ssl.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2F675386773fd5dab2b84da8770c511b8dd16e2e5e.bin" name="wistia_dgoosakyuf_html" style="display:block;height:100%;position:relative;width:100%;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"></embed></object><noscript itemprop="description"><p>buddyTruk is a mobile app for social hauling; connecting you with a local driver and their vehicle to please your moving needs.</p></noscript></div></div>
        <script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
        <script>
        wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("dgoosakyuf");
        </script>
        <script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/dgoosakyuf/metadata.js"></script>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Website link: http://www.buddytruk.com/temp

Comment: Weird... your code looks fine. Just to be sure though you could try changing double quotes to single quotes and maybe update your bootstrap to the latest incase there was a bug fix? 3.0.1 to 3.1.1 in your case.

Comment: @Myles so it works whenever i scroll down the page and come back to it, however, the initial hover does not stop the carousel from transitioning. is there a way that i could have the carousel automatically paused whenever the video is started?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pause the carousel when the video is played for the first time. Add this below your embed code.

```
<script>
// embed code here

wistiaEmbed.bind("play", function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
    console.log('Video is playing, stopping carousel');
});
</script>
```

Check the console to see if that message is coming out.